# Xcode5: selecting both "Mac App Store" radio button and "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" Code Sign Identity not possible?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5, code-signing

## SETUP:

- OS X 10.9 13A603
- Xcode 5.0.1 (5A2053)

I have a Mac app which is currently in the Mac App Store. This app is *not* distributed directly outside of the MAS.

I am trying to submit a new version for the first time in a while. This is the first time I've submitted with Xcode 5 (or Mavericks of course). In Xcode 5, there have been many changes related to provisioning profiles, code signing, and "Mac App Team" management (e.g. lots of "helpful" new UI).

I have also had to recreate my certificates and my development and production provisioning profiles for this app in particular. So a lot has changed since the last time I submitted this app to the MAS.

Note: my App target's `Archive` action uses the `Release` build configuration. So I use `Release` for submitting to the MAS.

## PROBLEM:

I can't seem to simultaneously select the **Signing: Mac App Store** radio button in my target's `General` Tab while *also* selecting my **distribution code-signing identity** (`3rd Party Mac Developer Application`) in my target's `Build Settings` tab.

## STEPS:

Assume my certificates and provisioning profiles are correctly installed (yes, I realize this is a big assumption, but everything seems to be installed and working properly. Let's just assume for a minute).

1. Open Xcode. Select my app's target. See `General` tab.
2. Select `Signing: Mac App Store` radio button. See `Team` popup change to correct team setting automatically. So far so good.
3. Click `Build Settings` tab.
4. Notice that `Code Signing Identity` is set to `Mac Developer` for ***both* Debug and Release** (Xcode changes this automatically whenever you select the radio button in the previous step)
5. Under `Code Signing Identity > Release`, change to `3rd Party Mac Developer Application` ([Apple's docs say this is the correct identity](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572-CH16-SW7) for MAS submission)
6. Go back to `General` tab.

## EXPECTED:

**Signing: Mac App Store** radio button should still be selected

## ACTUAL:

***Signing: None*** radio button is now selected. `Team` popup has been changed to `None`.

## NOTES:

Am I doing something wrong?

Does this even matter? If this radio button has no effect, I'm fine just ignoring it. But then why is it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Signing radio box to None and configure your identity and provisioning in the target's build settings. I've *never* used that signing option in the general tab.

Comment: Thx! At this point I'm fairly certain you're right that these radio buttons are best ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the radio button is associated with the "automatic" code signing settings. If you manually specify a code signing identity the radio button will be set to "none", but your application will still be signed with the manually set identity and that is all that matters. (all this is assuming the certificate was set up for MAS distribution etc).

Comment: Sorry Brad, this is not my question. I only distribute this app through the MAS. But even if I didn't, I really don't think this question has anything to do with needing separate targets for MAS distribution vs. direct distribution. The problem described here is only relevant to the target which is destined for MAS distribution and is not solved by (or even related to) a possible separate target for direct distribution.

Comment: @ToddDitchendorf the reason why I thought that is because you say you are using `3rd Party Mac Developer Application` which as far as I know is for distribution outside the MAS only.

Comment: I am under the impression that it is the exact opposite. I believe `3rd Party Mac Developer Application` is for **MAS only**. Here's the Apple docs stating that the `3rd Party Mac Developer Application` code signing identity is necessary for distribution through MAS: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572-CH16-SW7 Can you point me to Apple docs which state otherwise?

Comment: @ToddDitchendorf I'm pretty sure that the radio button is associated with the "automatic" code signing settings. If you manually specify a code signing identity the radio button will be set to "none", but your application will still be signed with the set identity and that is all that matters.

Comment: Ah. OK. So this is actually expected behavior? Wow, I find it very confusing, but I would not be terribly surprised to learn you are right. OK, thanks! I'd like to get some consensus from the crowd here at SO that this is actually expected. Hopefully others will chime in and agree. If you post a separate answer stating this is actually expected behavior, that will help move things along (and I will accept it). Otherwise, I'll add one myself later.

Comment: @ToddDitchendorf It is a bit confusing. if you are the owner of the account then you can just set up the automatic profile by using the drop down menu below the radio buttons. I only use the override for development when I have the cert/key (shared by the team), but not the account credentials.

Comment: @BradAllred, certificates for distribution outside the Mac App Store begin with `Developer ID Application`.